# Grep for a specific element

Tags: command-line, grep

I am kind of stuck in a tricky situation. I have a file, whose contents look like this:

```
3               2017-05-30      2017-09-29
2               2017-05-27      2017-08-26
1               2017-05-27      2017-08-26
```

Now, user selects to modify a date by choosing labelNum which would be values in column 1. Upon prompt, if user enters 3. I want to print column 2.

So I wrote.

```
cat temp.txt | grep $labelNum | awk '{print $2}'
```

If `labelNum` is 3, I get the output as `2017-05-30`

But, if user enters `labelNum` as 2, then i get:

```
2017-05-30
2017-05-27
2017-05-27
```

Because it is looking for '2' everywhere in the .txt file.
However, I want the column 2 for `labelNum` 2, which would be `2017-05-27`

Is there a way to do this? I tried using awk to replace grep but no luck.

Thanks.

Edit:
The rows are dynamic and can change as and when more entries are added to text file. So can't really use sed to skip to the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single ***awk***:

```
awk -v lbl=$labelNum '$1 == lbl{ print $2 }' temp.txt
```

---

- `-v lbl=$labelNum` - passing in `labelNum` variable value into awk script
- `$1 == lbl` - if the 1st column value equal to the variable value - executes the followed expression

Answer (score 0):

You also can stay around your solution:

```
cat temp.txt | grep ^$labelNum | awk '{print $2}'
```

Which will match at the beginning of the line, or

```
awk '/^'$labelNum'/{print $2}' temp.txt
```

Would work alike, but the escaping is tricky inside of awk.